# Displaying image or gif during boot in ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu

Is there any way to add a image/gif/short video during boot instead of showing the logs in ubuntu server 20.04 (no desktop environment) running in raspberry pi 4b?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the boot process of Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4B to display an image, GIF, or short video instead of the usual logs. You'll need to have the image, GIF, or short video that you want to display during boot. Make sure it's compatible with the Raspberry Pi hardware.
You have to install Plymouth. This is a boot splash screen utility that can replace the default text-based boot screens with graphical animations. Install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt install plymouth
```

Comment: I already have plymouth and found a way to change text but i'm not undertsanding how to add image/gif